# Como fazer uma requisição HTTP em Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rest, http

Como faço uma requisicao HTTP em Ruby? Preciso implementar uma API, e para isso é necessario fazer uma solicitação REST para tal URL, como faco um POST para tal solicitação?

Comment: Procure sobre a gem httparty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está disponível na documentação do ruby [DOC](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html), o exemplo abaixo

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('http://www.example.com/search.cgi')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'q' => ['ruby', 'perl'], 'max' => '50')
puts res.body
```

Comment: Mas ai os parametros eu passo onde, e tambem como tratar a resposta do servidor e o que e => uri, 'q' => ['ruby', 'perl'], 'max' => '50'

Comment: Isso 'q' é um parametro, e 'max' é outro

Comment: Faz sentido, o res.body é a resposta do servidor ?

Answer (score 0):

A gem [HTTP (http.rb)](https://github.com/httprb/http) facilita esse trabalho. Para instalar, basta adicionar ao seu Gemfile:

```
gem "http"
```

e executar `bundle install` no shell.

```
require 'http'
response = HTTP.post("https://api.test/post", :params => {:id => 5})
response.body # retorna um objeto representando a resposta
response.code # retorna o código HTTP da resposta, e.g. 404, 500, 200
```

Se você precisar de autenticação, basta:

```
HTTP.basic_auth(:user => "user", :pass => "pass")
  .get("https://example.com")
```

ou se quiser passar a autorização de forma "crua":

```
HTTP.auth("Bearer VGhlIEhUVFAgR2VtLCBST0NLUw")
  .get("https://example.com")
```